# Is there any way to increase the damage die on my Hagbound Witch's claw attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, natural-weapon, witch

The [hagbound witch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/archetypes/paizo-witch-archetypes/hagbound-witch-archetype/) gains a d4 claw attack at level 1 but they never get stronger. I was wondering if there are any feats to help improve this. Or maybe give additional effects to claw attacks in general.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5):

### Improved Natural Attack

[Improved Natural Attack](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improved%20Natural%20Attack) is a Feat that will increase the damage to 1d6. It's not a great return on investment, but it does exactly what you want. You won't qualify for it until level 8+ because it requires +4 BAB or higher.

Note that this is a "Monster Feat"; usually, this isn't a problem because they're not officially restricted to player characters, but some GM's might do so anyway.

### Other Feats

- [Rending Claws](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Rending%20Claws) gives an extra 1d6 damage to your second successful claw attack in a round.
- [Possessed Hand](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Possessed%20Hand) provides +1 insight to hit and damage at the cost of -2 to Concentration checks.
- [Mother's Gift](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mother%27s%20Gift), if you are a changeling (which fits the class archetype), provides an untyped +1 to hit and damage with claws.
- [Eldritch Claws](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Eldritch%20Claws) causes your claws to overcome DR/magic and DR/silver.

### Typical damage increases

Besides the obvious necklace of mighty blows and general party buffs (eg bardic courage, etc), a common way to boost your own damage is increasing the size and effective size of your attack. You can only benefit from one of each type of effect at a time. Here are the most common options for those:

- [Enlarge Person](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Enlarge%20Person) (witch 1 etc.), [Steal Size](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Steal%20Size) (witch 2, etc.) [Legendary Proportions](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Legendary%20Proportions) (witch 7, etc.), and others increase you and your claws' actual size by 1 or more steps.
- [Strong Jaw](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Strong%20Jaw) (druid/hunter/ranger), despite its name, increases the effective size of *any* natural attack by 2 die steps (1d4 becomes 1d8; 1d6 becomes 1d10).

Combining both effects will grant you 2d6 damage (2d8 with Improved Natural Attack) on your claws (and may give you a greater size bonus to Strength than your Hunched Muscle feature, at some levels).

Comment: No love for Magic Fang? Could try a wand for early on, and later have it Permanencied.

Comment: Eh I gave a nod to the necklace (had handwraps which are also valid but awkward to use) of mighty blows and enhancement bonuses are so pervasive I don't feel like it fits the scope of the question since it specifically says damage die.

Comment: I first read that as "improve the claw attack", not "improve the damage die". But well, *English*. Anyway, upvote.